# fopen: failed to open stream

Tags: php, linux

I recently configured google cloud for my web app. There is a piece of code I have written that creates a flat file in a directory. This piece of code works very well on localhost but is giving the following error in google cloud:

```
Warning: fopen(nav/nav_dump_20181125.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/report_today_val.php on line 171
```

I tried following things:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/nav
sudo chgrp apache /var/www/html/nav
sudo chown apache /var/www/html/nav/
```

my code is:

```
$newf = fopen ($newfname, 'w');
```

But nothing seems to work. Can someone please help why I am unable to create this file?

Comment: The user running the script (wwwroot?) is not supposed to create a file in this directory. Obviously a security setting. 
Your commands from the shell do only affect YOU (the user you have connected with) but not the webserver.

Comment: Any idea which security setting I should change to allow the web server to write in this directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the permission from the root default folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
```

Answer (score -1):

u should run this command to change these files under the `nav` dir.

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/nav`

ur command just make u get the permission to write `nav`, but the files under it does not changed.

Comment: em...  can u show me the result of command `ls -al /var/www/html/nav` ?

Comment: total 4
drwxrwsrwx. 2 apache apache    6 Nov 25 01:21 .
drwxrwsrwx. 7 apache apache 4096 Nov 25 01:03 ..